# 404 API request with pagination in prod mode but works in dev

Tags: angular, laravel, angular-httpclient

I use a Laravel API and an Angular service to make my application.
I'm doing a pagination for my array with Angular and I make a HTTP request with this function in my service :

```
getPagination(page): Observable<any> {
     return this.httpClient.get<any>(environment.apiBaseUrl + 'test/?page=' + page);
  }
```

When I trigger it I get the data with the pagination but when I want to get another page in prod I get a 404 error because it uses an URL that I don't even give.

I'm supposed to have this url:

```
http://prodUrl/back/api/test?page=2
```

But I get this :

```
http://prodUrl/api/test?page=2
```

Here is the function in the Laravel API

```
public function getAll()
    {
        $stuff = MyStuff::orderByDesc('updated_at')->paginate(50); 
        return response()->json($stuff, 200);
    }
```

The route:

```
 Route::get('test', [Controller::class, 'getAll']);
```

When I make a `console.log()` of the `environment.apiBaseUrl` in the first call to get the first page I have the right url and same thing for the content:

```
current_page: 1
first_page_url: "http://prodUrl/back/api/test?page=1"
from: 1
last_page: 3
last_page_url: "http://prodUrl/back/api/test?page=3"
links: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
next_page_url: "http://prodUrl/back/api/test?page=2"
path: "http://prodUrl/back/api/test"
per_page: 50
prev_page_url: null
to: 50
total: 146
```

So why the HTTP request doesn't use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get the url I need by passing the url of the current page then use `substring()` to remove the page number to add the paramter like below:

```
 let urlSplit = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('=') + 1);
 return this.httpClient.get<any>(urlSplit + page);
```